# How to implement the operator [] for set a value in a two dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, operators

I have the following two dimensional array:

```
 val arr = Array(3){column-> IntArray(5){it+column} }
```

i want to set the value 5 in the place arr[1][3] (index 1,3)
so when i write the following code:

```
 arr[1,3] = 5
```

I'm getting the following error:

> The integer literal does not conform to the expected type IntArray

When trying to use IDE fix (Alt+Shift+Enter) it creates the following function:

```
private operator fun <T> Array<T>.set(i: Int, unit: Unit, value: Int)
```

Now i don't understand the meaning of the *unit* variable and don't know how implement this function

Comment: I don't quite get it. Why don't you just use the syntax `arr[1][3] = 5` instead of the comma? You don't need any custom operator for this

Comment: @Joffrey, just for learning purpose mate

Comment: Ah I see, then yes it's just about the incorrect print statement, with parentheses instead of curly braces ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me, with your version of the `set` operator!

You need a getter too, if you want to use the same syntax:

```
private operator fun Array<IntArray>.get(i: Int, j:Int) = get(i).get(j)
```

And your string code needs curly braces, when you're wrapping an expression:

```
println("--------${arr[1][3]}")
```

Not sure about the `unit` parameter in the auto-generated code, that's a weird one

Comment: the curly braces :)... Thanks! maybe the unit related somehow to T and generics

Comment: Yeah you could be right, I can't think of any other reason to pass in ``Unit`` as a parameter apart from as a placeholder!